# Slick2d Animation not working

Tags: animation, render, slick2d

I'm making my first ever game using Slick2d, but I ran into trouble trying to use Animation.

What I'm trying to do is have a main Entity class and movement and render components. What I want is when the player presses on an arrow key, the walking animation for that direction starts playing, and when they're not pressing, the animation stops.

When I first tested the components I used just one Image for the different directions, and it worked fine. Which only makes me more confused. The game screen comes up and so long as I don't press down any of the arrow keys. When I do, the proper (direction-wise) sprite animation begins and the position changes correctly, but when it reaches the last frame, the game window closes and I get an error. This is what it's telling me on the console:

```
Wed Mar 21 13:20:47 PDT 2012 INFO:Slick Build #274
Wed Mar 21 13:20:47 PDT 2012 INFO:LWJGL Version: 2.0b1
Wed Mar 21 13:20:47 PDT 2012 INFO:OriginalDisplayMode: 1366 x 768 x 32 @60Hz
Wed Mar 21 13:20:47 PDT 2012 INFO:TargetDisplayMode: 750 x 600 x 0 @0Hz
Wed Mar 21 13:20:48 PDT 2012 INFO:Starting display 750x600
Wed Mar 21 13:20:48 PDT 2012 INFO:Use Java PNG Loader = true
Wed Mar 21 13:20:49 PDT 2012 INFO:Controllers not available
Wed Mar 21 13:20:52 PDT 2012 ERROR:null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at bunny.component.render.RenderComponent.render(RenderComponent.java:22)
at bunny.entity.Entity.render(Entity.java:177)
at bunny.game.BunnyGame.render(BunnyGame.java:56)
at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:681)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:408)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:318)
at bunny.game.BunnyGame.main(BunnyGame.java:66)
Wed Mar 21 13:20:52 PDT 2012 ERROR:Game.render() failure - check the game code.
org.newdawn.slick.SlickException: Game.render() failure - check the game code.
at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:684)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:408)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:318)
at bunny.game.BunnyGame.main(BunnyGame.java:66)
```

Since it seems to be having trouble rendering, I checked to make sure that everywhere the sprite is used it's not still trying to treat it as an Image instead of Animation. I also made sure that render has the correct parameters, calls draw, and when that still didn't work I tried having it render only the current frame since I knew render worked for Image. None of that made my problem go away.

I've been searching online for quite a while now and I'm mostly sure now that the problem is probably in either my movement component, or my rendering one. Thing is, the only tutorial I have found that somewhat addresses this is http://slick.cokeandcode.com/wiki/doku.php?id=entity_tutorial

This is my Render Component Class:

```
public class RenderComponent extends Component {    
Image image;

public RenderComponent(String id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sb, Graphics gr) 
{
    Vector2f pos = owner.getPosition();
    image.draw(pos.x, pos.y);
}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sb, int delta) {
    image = owner.getDirection().getCurrentFrame();
}
}
```

This is my Arrow Key Movement class:

```
public class ArrowKeyMovement extends Component{

float direction;
float speed;

public ArrowKeyMovement( String id )
{
    this.id = id;
}

public float getSpeed()
{
    return speed;
}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sb, int delta)
{
    // 0 - up, 1 - down, 2 - left, 3 - right
    Input input = gc.getInput();
    Vector2f position = owner.getPosition();

    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP))
    {
        owner.setSprite(0);
        if (owner.getDirection().isStopped()) {
            owner.getDirection().restart();
        }
        owner.getDirection().update(delta);
        position.y -= delta * 0.2f;
    }
    else if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN))
    {
        owner.setSprite(1);
        if (owner.getDirection().isStopped()) {
            owner.getDirection().restart();
        }
        owner.getDirection().update(delta);
        position.y += delta * 0.2f;
    }
    else if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT))
    {
        owner.setSprite(2);
        if (owner.getDirection().isStopped()) {
            owner.getDirection().restart();
        }
        owner.getDirection().update(delta);
        position.x -= delta * 0.2f;
    }
    else if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT))
    {
        owner.setSprite(3);
        if (owner.getDirection().isStopped()) {
            owner.getDirection().restart();
        }
        owner.getDirection().update(delta);
        position.x += delta * 0.2f;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (!(owner.getDirection().isStopped())){
            owner.getDirection().stop();
        }
    }

    owner.setPosition(position);
}
}
```

Inside my Entity class I call RenderComponent like so:

```
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sb, Graphics gr)
{
    if(renderComponent != null)
        renderComponent.render(gc, sb, gr);
}
```

I'm sorry I'm being vague about what my problem is, but I swear I really tried to figure it out by myself. If I didn't give enough information, tell me and I will provide more. Thank you for your time! And if you have a more detailed tutorial I really appreciate it.

Comment: When loading the animation, are you sure that the size of your frames list is the same as the number of images/frames that you're loading into memory? With a null pointer exception during rendering, I wonder if you're leaving one or more of your Animation frames empty?

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that the image gets initialized in your RenderComponent class before it's render() method is called, which uses the image variable?

In other words, are you sure the update() method gets called at least once in RenderComponent *before* the render() method is called?